# Can a single nVidia RTX 3080 drive 6 monitors or do I need to buy two cards?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I want to build a set up with 6 monitors for productivity but I also want acceleration play games (even though most of the time they use one monitor). Can a single nVidia RTX 3080 drive 3 monitors or do I have to end up with 2 video cards?

Resolution wise, it shouldn't be a problem. The nVidia RTX 3080 can drive up to 7680x4320 (33m pixels) and I intend to use 6 monitors at 2560 x 1440 (22m pixels) but the problems is connections. I cannot find any card that has connectors for 6 monitors. They all seem to have 3 display ports and an HDMI or something around that.

Answer (score 1):

RTX 3080 supports up to 4 displays according to specs on NVIDIA site.

Consumer-grade cards generally don't offer support for more than 4 displays. It's a niche feature available only on specialized cards, like for example Matrox C680 which has 6 MiniDP outputs.

If you need more outputs, you'll need a second card. I'm not sure if buying a cheaper one would work. It's possible that you could use the more powerful card to render frames into the buffer and then transfer them to cheap output-only card - that's how laptop hybrid graphics work - but I doubt official drivers support this on a desktop.

Comment: Could you not daisy chain the Displayport connections? Or would it limit the resolution?

Comment: @spikey_richie Nice idea, I didn't think of that. Unfortunately official RTX 3080 specs say that 4 displays is max, daisy-chained or not. Anyway the DP throughput would be shared between all daisy-chained displays, but I think 2x1440p on a single port could work assuming GPU's max display count isn't exceeded.

Comment: so to connect 5 monitors  I might need another 3080?

Comment: @Luk What do you want to use the 5th monitor for? Maybe a cheapo card like GT 710 would work?

Comment: AMD cards are "consumer grade" and support six monitors, although few have six outputs and so this usually requires a DP hub. Typically, at least four of the monitors must be displayport. If memory serves, all of the cards based on GCN architecture or later (basically anything that isn't ancient) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer could be just dazychaining the moniters if they support it if you have a few extra cables lying around or are willing to throw a few extra bucks at some more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a motherboard with the i7 11700k and so the motherboard has one HDMI port so I can operate 5 monitors on my system. This will be my new 32" Odyssey Neo G8 as the center monitor and 1 28" monitor placed on each side of the 32" monitor and my 2 24" Monitors placed next to each other above the 32" monitor.

My problem is that the max resolution speced for the RTX3080-based graphic cards is 7560x4k and this would mean that I cannot use the resolution of the 28" monitors, 3840x2160 as horizontally 3 monitors is 11500 which is too big for the rtx 3080.

I was already surprised that I could have 5 monitors mixing the MSI rtx3080 and the output from the motherboard and that W11 had no problem handling this.
To my knowledge, two MSI RTX 3080 cannot be placed onto a single motherboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).